# What is the technology behind 37 Signals Breeze

Tags: email

I was thinking about this the other day in the shower and i realised I had no clue how you would "roll" up your own version of [37 signals breeze](http://basecamp.com/breeze) - And ever since it's been bugging me.

Specifically If i and my friends create a group email mygroup@breeze.com

and from my personal email i email that group address, how does 37 signals intercept it and thus lookup their database to find the members original emails and then email them all.

I wasnt sure if this should have been posted over on server fault so my apologies if i made a mistake.

Comment: To me it looks similar to any other mailing list provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing remotely mystical here. Their servers receive all email to `@breeze.com` email addresses, just like Google's servers receive all `@gmail.com` email. There's no "intercepting", of your personal mail, you're just sending an email directly to them.

When they receive an email, they look up which individual email addresses are part of that "group". They forward the email to them. There's nothing new or interesting in this setup, and the only technologies in use here is SMTP, which is a 30 year old protocol. It's literally just email and a very small server-side scripted app.

Pretty much every [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) in existence supports this.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is very simple.

1. You send an e-mail to `example`@breeze123.com
2. Server receives the e-mail
3. Checks who belongs to the group `example`
4. Checks whether any BBCs contain non group members
5. Server sends message to group member (except sender) and non group members from point 4

Gmail supports this too for enterprise e-mail. Probably many other services too. It's quite a ubiquitous concept.

[IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) (or should I say servers using IMAP) usually support a lot of hooks that you can assign scripts to (e.g. e-mail received, post-login etc.)